# How to safely root the Samsung Galaxy Tab A 2017 (SM-T380)?

Tags: rooting, samsung, root-access, 7.1-nougat

I am wondering what would be a safe way to root my Samsung Galaxy Tab A 2017 (SM-T380)?

I understand there is CF-AutoRoot and such but I have **no** experience in rooting any device with that method and I'm extremely scared that if I attempt to root my tablet with CF-AutoRoot and such that my device will get bricked.

Details about the tablet below.

• **Android Version**: 7.1.1

• **Security Patch Level**: January 1, 2018

• **Build Number**: NMF26X.T380DXU1ARB3

• **"OEM Unlock" option available ✔**

I also have another question. The tablet has a pending update to Android Oreo, if I were to update the tablet and the tablet was rooted at the time I updated it would it affect my root?

Answer (score -1):

I removed my RMM prenormal with miracle box no box and after finding the twrp tar on xda used it to install a custom zip file i made with superr kitchen and a rom from samfirm .
There are no roms a